# Always on the bottom footer is not working

Tags: html, css, apache, xampp

I made an always on the bottom footer with this code from codepen.

HTML

```
<div class="content">

    <header>
        <p>blabla</p>
    </header>

    <main>
        <p>blaBlabla blub</p>
    </main>
</div>

<footer> 
    <p>more bla</p>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
*{
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

html{
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 250px;
    min-height: 100%;

    background-color: white;
}

.content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;

    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

It works fine when I call the page with "file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/folder/index.html" but when I call it with "http://localhost/folder/index.html" it dont. I hope somebody can help me because I really get frustrated.

Comment: Can you share the codepen?

Comment: You probably haven't used a relative file path for your css.

Comment: after opening your index.html file in browser .. click right and select view source .. On view source check  the css file linked properly with index.html or not.

Comment: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/cbracco/pen/zekgx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link to the css file is probably not resolving on the server as your css rules are correct.

> Here is all you need to know about relative file paths:
>
> - Starting with "/" returns to the root directory and starts there
> - Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts there
> - Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards and starts there (and so on...)
> - To move forward, just start with the first subdirectory and keep moving forward
>
> -[Source and more information](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/)

Assuming your file is in the same folder, try to use this instead:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./yourStyleFileName.css">
```

Assuming your file is in the root css folder for example, try to use this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/yourStyleFileName.css">
```

You should be able to create your own relative path quite easily.

Comment: Dont know why but it works now. I just worked on another problem. Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: Programming logic hahaha